# Identify a user device

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm new in mobile and web development.

We want to give access to some business methods on mobile phones/tablets.

Now a question arose: How to identify a user.

Our users work on jobsites. Even with desktop applications they rarely use user/password combinations (infact most wanted an auto login for a pc, and from there SingleSignOn is used for the program).

So I think based on experience with the users a traditional login mechanism won't be accepted.

However we want to provide at least some basic security. We thought on the following:

1. A user can log to the server once with a mobile device
2. Administrator can link the device to an existing user
3. Afterwards user can just use his device without logon (Identification of user is then done wia some unique identification of the phone)

If we would write programs for each plattform we could (i think) use something like DeviceExtendedProperties.DeviceUniqueId for Windows Phone. Maybe create / store a token and send it to the Server in step 1 which then is used next time for identification.

But we thought it could maybe also be possible without specific applications for the device types and only use of one website for all devices. Therefore we want to use a webpage and jquery mobile to give a more native looking on the diverent devices.

So the problem is: How to identify a phone via web browser?

Is there some cool jquery or javascript function for device identification that i missed?

Or are there better approaches?

Comment: Are you sure a standard solution with auto-login (like what's used in SO) wouldn't be accepted ? As you almost never enter a login screen, it's not painful. BTW there's **no** not hacky unique identifier of a browser, this would of course be a privacy problem.

Answer (score 0):

### How to identify a phone via web browser?

Why not setting a cookie ? Sure the user would have to relog if he uses multiple browsers or disabled cookies, but this is an easy solution.

[Here's more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922658/best-way-to-identify-a-user-uniquely)

Comment: I'm a bit ambivalent about using cookies. I try to explain why: For login a cookie could be useful. But if at a later point someone wants a "real" app I thought about the following: Using jquery mobile first for a mobile website. If mobile solution is really used (or someone really wants a sort of "app"), convert the site with PhoneGap to a sort of "app" (but keep HTML access for other devices) (personally i hate having an "app" if i could do the same thing on any phone with just a browser, but i think this is mostly opinion). PhoneGap and Cookies just don't seem to work together.

Comment: Well if you develop an app for this later, storing the information is not that hard. I mean - you have way more power over the device so saving a credential is a piece of cake.