# How to Log Votes of Users who are not signed in

Tags: php, logging

I am creating a simple module of like/dislike. My site has no login system, which means the visitors are not the logged in members.. 
How can I log their LIKES/DISLIKES, so they can not repeat the same action again and again for same post?
Can i log their unique IP or mac address..
any help?

Comment: Yes, IP/MAC should be unique enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to Identify a user uniquely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922658/best-way-to-identify-a-user-uniquely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP/MAC is not perfect as it will identify different users in the same household as one.
Cookie is not perfect as they can easily be cleared (or the user can just use a private/incognito mode)

The best solution I've found - yet still not perfect - to identify users without a login  is to use a long lived cookie/session as well as storing session ID, IP and User Agent along with the like/dislike ID to enforce any rule you would like to set.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3922920/2657607), [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) is also an option to explore.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

to log their IP address, you can also create a session in their browser in case of IP change where the users IP is not static

Comment: This isn't going to be a great method as most IP addresses are not static.

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies. Check for cookie before voting and set cookie after voting. It's not perfect either, because user can delete cookies, but if you want to be 100% sure then you must have registered users.